# Place popup above taskbar WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Im trying to get a popup to appear above the taskbar always regardless of the main window position.
What can we do in WPF to achieve this?

How do I get a WPF popup to always appear above the windows taskbar?
Thanks!

Comment: try always on top with a state less window.

Comment: are you after a notification icon like implementation? if so, there is a very good implementation on [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon)

Answer (score 0):

In form load event make like changes.

int screenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height-(width of your form  popup);

int screenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width-(height of your form popup);

this.Location = new Point(screenWidth, screenHeight);